# zedgraph x2axis scrolling

Tags: c#

I am using x2axis along with xaxis in Zedgraph. Is it possible to have both axis scroll together? The zoom event seems to work ok, but when using the scroll event, it scrolls the curve linked to the xaxis but not the curve linked to the x2axis.
Regards Robert.